# Pygame float accuracy collision detect

Tags: python, pygame, simulation

I am building a physical simulation and would like to make a pygame visualization.
For position and velocity calculations I use `Vector2`, which works very well.
It would be helpful to use the built-in rectangular collision detection. Unfortunately I have to round the current position to one pixel for the rectangle first. Since 1 pixel was set to 1 meter in my simulation, I can only determine physical collisions within 1 meter. Does anyone have an idea how I could solve this problem? My only idea would be to change the scale to 10 pixels for 1 meter to get an accuracy of 10 centimeters, but then I can only display 100m at 1000 pixels. Perhaps somebody knows a good solution for that! Thank you for your help!

Comment: Keep your variables as float.  Only convert to pixels for display.

Comment: I do that. But I was asking for a float collision detection (perhaps directly via pygame)

Comment: @Skywalker There is no "float collision detection" in pygame. You have to implement it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

If your code serves the purpose to solve a simulation you should separate the simulation from the visualization. Because now you are experiencing the fact, that you have to limit your simulation, because of visualization issues. That should not be the case.

My suggestion would be to use a combination of numpy and scipy to run your simulation without pygame (even Vector2 or Rect from pygame). If you need to detect collisions in you simulation you can implement a rectangle collision yourself very quickly:

```
class Rectangle(object):
    def __init__(self, left, bottom, width, height):
        self.left = left
        self.bottom = bottom
        self.width = width
        self.height = height

    @property
    def right(self):
        return self.left + self.width

    @property
    def top(self):
        return self.bottom + self.height

    def collide_with_rectangle(self, other):
        if self.left > other.right or self.right < other.left or self.bottom > other.top or self.top < other.top:
            return False
        return True
```

The advantage of this approach is, that you can separate the visualization from your simulation logic. For example, if you recognize that pygame is not fitting your needs, you can switch very easy to matplotlib or any other framework.

When you separated your simulation logic you can scale your visualization easily. Because you take all points from your simulation and multiply a visualization/zoom factor.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and your suggestion to not use a visualization module for calculations. Thanks for you example (I found a little mistake, the last comparison has to be "other.bottom").
Nevertheless I have headings for the rectangles. Therefore this solution unfortunately does not solve the problem and a module that can be used out of the box would be nice.
If somebody knows an implementation I would be very happy. Otherwise I will try to solve it via vectors but I am afraid that a not perfect implementation can cause performance issues

Comment: Seems like "separating axis theorem" could be the solution...